# How to create visualisations like the one in Windows Media Player?

Tags: visualization, windows-media-player

I am trying to work on a project which involves capturing live data and projecting some image depending on the input. The output is required to be something similar to the **Visualizations in Windows Media Player**.

For example http://www.superwasp.net/weblog/uploaded_images/ribbonwmpvisual-768934.jpg
or http://www.plasmavis.com/acidwax/ReadMe_files/image001.jpg
or anything similar.

So basically I want to know if there is any toolkit/library to create my own visualizations? Since it depends on live input, I need some library or tool(and not a video) so that I can generate anything like that, depending on the input.

Please do tell if you have any knowledge to implement anything similar(if not exactly)

Thanks!

PS:I don't know what SO tags I can associate my question with. So please edit them accordingly as you feel.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much source code out there on how to make visualizations for Microsoft's Windows Media Player, but there is one tutorial found on Channel 9 titled [Winter Visualization for Windows Media Player in C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Winter-Visualization-for-Windows-Media-Player-in-C).  There is also some information on MSDN concerning the [WMP Plugin Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that only gets you as far as an empty shell of a plug-in.

To learn how do extremely visually stunning effects though, you need to study demos from graphic libraries such those included with the [Cinder Library](http://libcinder.org/gallery/). You need to learn the math and physics involved. I recommend studying the HodginParticles demo for a start.  There are several sound visualizers included within the [Cinder Library](http://libcinder.org/gallery/) examples as well.

Comment: Sorry if my question seemed ambiguous. But I don't want to make visualisations for Windows Media Player. But some visualization based on music.I found out about FMOD (C++ library) to analyse the music into the frequency spectrum and then use that data to visualise using opengl.

Comment: The Cinder Library can do that too. There is even an example included that changes the visual with music and also another that breaks sound down into octives to trigger events.  To demonstrate the Visual Power of C++, Microsoft pushed primarily three open source libraries, Cinder, Box2D, and OpenFrameworks at the [GoingNative 2013 Symposium](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013) regarding the new C++14 ISO standard.